# Android - DownloadListener or AsyncTask

Tags: android, webview, android-asynctask

am trying to download from web page some files by clinking the url with webview handling the download not the browser

if i use DownloadListener  it works perfectly with one problem i cant see the progressbar

if i use the AsyncTask i have to put the url in the code to download it i can just click the url and start downloading

my question is how can i let the AsyncTask download any url from the web without sitting the

downloadFile.execute("the url to the file you want to download");

or how i can  create progressbar for DownloadListener

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    myProgressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressbar_Horizontal);
    new Thread(myThread).start();
    webview.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient());
    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webview.setInitialScale(50); 
    webview.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true); 
    webview.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
    webview.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
    webview.loadUrl("http://localhost/index.php");
    webview.setWebViewClient(new DownloadWebViewClient());
    webview.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {

       @Override
       public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent,
             String contentDisposition, String mimetype,
             long contentLength) {
           InputStream is;
           try {
               URL u = new URL(url);
               HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
               con.setRequestMethod("GET");
               con.setDoOutput(true);
               con.connect();
               is = con.getInputStream();


           // Path and File where to download the APK
           String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/apdroid/";
           String fileName = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
           File dir = new File(path);
           dir.mkdirs(); // creates the download directory if not exist
           File outputFile = new File(dir, fileName);
           FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);

           // Save file from URL to download directory on external storage
           byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
           int len = 0;
           while ((len = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
               fos.write(buffer, 0, len);
           }
           fos.close();
           is.close();


           Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
           String name = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/apdroid/" + url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
           intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(name)), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
           startActivity(intent);


       }catch (IOException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
        }
       }
    });


 }



protected void install(String fileName) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}



private Runnable myThread = new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
       while (myProgress < 100) {
          try {
             myHandle.sendMessage(myHandle.obtainMessage());
             Thread.sleep(1000);
          } catch (Throwable t) {
          }
       }
    }

    Handler myHandle = new Handler() {

       @Override
       public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
          myProgress++;
          myProgressBar.setProgress(myProgress);
       }

    };

 };









private class HelloWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {










@Override
public void onReceivedError(WebView view,int errorCode,String description,String failingUrl) {
   try {view.stopLoading();} catch(Exception e){}
   try {view.clearView();} catch(Exception e){}
   view.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/wifi.html");
}
    }
```

i just want to have ProgressBar when i download any file from my page

and i cant use asyncTask because i have to put the files in the code not by clicking at them

Comment: hard to extract your requirement from the question...?

Comment: sorry if i was not clear enough

Answer (score 0):

You should probably be `overriding the URL loading` process, and recognize by some way if any URL is being loaded whose resource you would want to download.
As soon as you detect this, stop loading the page and start the AsyncTask with this URL.